# Drawer / hamburger menu in React Native

Tags: react-native, drawer, hamburger-menu

I need to create an app using react native in both android and iOS and i'm still a newbie. So,now i need to implement a drawer like shown in the image above.I've already searched for an example or project that meets with my needs but too badly, i couldn't find anything suitable for me.So can you help me and thank you

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-1_Fi6T2l1LY/VUfHyQlwenI/AAAAAAAAC8g/wkWN42gNaDw/s320/device-2015-05-04-101820_1.gif

Answer (score 2):

You could use this library:

https://github.com/react-native-material-design/react-native-material-design

I think it can solve your problem

This RN starter has an example as well:

https://github.com/infinitered/ignite

Answer (score 2):

You should not implement it from scratch yourself but instead you can use a starter project like [this](https://github.com/start-react/native-starter-kit). If you want these animations on the drawer icon you can also check the Airbnb's [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-react-native).

Answer (score 1):

How to implement the hamburger menu with react-native-paper:
https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/guides/react-navigation/ ([arhive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20230131065131/https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/integrate-app-bar-with-react-navigation.html))

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@mdeepikayadav029/side-menu-bar-after-login-screen-in-react-native-4cabee7ca2b0

At the time, this one worked for me (0.63.4). The others I found were from previous versions (0.45) and required a lot of adjustments regarding newer version implementations. No other extra files are needed except these ones after creating a unmanaged blank project:

```
App.js
LoginScreen.js
HeaderComponent.js
FirstScreen.js
SecondScreen.js
```